# How to set first party session cookie on the browser from diffrent domain

Tags: reactjs, express, authentication, session, cookies

I am using express-session on the backend. My client is in React. My backend and the front end are hosted in two separate domains.

I am sending the session from the backend to my client using the set-cookie header which sets the session cookie in the browser.

However, I am having problems with the same site attribute. If I set it to 'none' it works only when the browser allows third-party cookies. if I set it to 'lax' or 'strict' it doesn't set the cookie in the browser.

I am guessing this is because of how the first-party and third-party cookies work.

I want to be able to set the session cookie as a first-party cookie so that I don't have to worry about my users blocking the third-party cookie on their browsers.

How can I achieve this?

1. do my backend and frontend need to be hosted under the same domain for this?
2. if yes, what is the best way to set a session cookie on the browser from an API that is hosted on a different URL?